# Use CommCtrl.pas or commctrl.h inside rc script

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, rc

I have a resource script (*.rc) that needs to use WIZ_CXDLG from commctrl.h/CommCtrl.pas. The original version does this via `#include`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, WIZ_CXDLG, WIZ_CYDLG
//...
```

However this doesn't compile in a Delphi XE6 project, neither with the Borland nor the MS resource compiler because commctrl.h isn't found.

What's the correct way to resolve this? I could probably download the Windows SDK but that seems like overkill.

**Edit:** FWIW - `#include`-ing CommCtrl.pas doesn't work. In XE6 brcc32 apparently chokes on the `WinApi.` prefix. In D2007 brcc32 stops at the interface uses clause. However we already successfully used simpler Pascal files like

```
unit MyProject_rc;

interface

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Cursor
//

const
  IDC_CURSOR_FOO = 1;
//[SNIP]

implementation

end.
```

Comment: "*commctrl.h isn't found*" - sounds like your search paths are not configured correctly.

Comment: @Remy Unless there's a Windows SDK installed, that header won't be present. For a Delphi install that would be perfectly common.

Answer (score 1):

I would compile this the Microsoft resource compiler, against the Windows SDK. That will mean installing the Windows SDK. You think that's overkill, but I personally feel it's a very important and useful resource for Windows developers.

If you really don't want to install the SDK, modify the resource file to include the necessary definitions.

```
#define WIZ_CXDLG   276
#define WIZ_CYDLG   140
// etc.
```